# Exporting Docx File with content disposition using AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am writing a handler as AWS Lambda Function which is supposed to wrap the content into the docx file. I am using the Content-Disposition in response headers in order to achieve the objective. Below is the code that I have written so far:

```
//Process Array Buffer and extract the plain content out of it
export const extractContent = async (data: Buffer) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    textract.fromBufferWithMime(
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      data,
      { preserveLineBreaks: true },
      (err, content) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(content);
        }
      }
    )
  );
};

export const handlerName = async (
  event: APIGatewayProxyEvent
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  if (event.body === null) {
    return ErrorResponse;
  }
  const result = await class.func(JSON.parse(event.body)); //returns an array buffer object
  if (result instanceof Error) {
    return ErrorResponse;
  }
  const content = await extractContent(result.data)
          .then(res => res)
          .catch(err => err);
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "'max-age=31536000'",
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Content-Disposition",
    "Content-Disposition": attachment; filename=fn.docx; filename*=UTF-8''fn.docx,
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.ms-word.document" 
  };
  return {
    body: content,
    headers,
    statusCode: 200,
  };
};
```

Now only string can be returned in APIGatewayResponse; hence I am not able to return byte object | stream | buffer instead. 
I am able to download the docx file but it is not getting opened in MS-Word; I am always getting a detailed error that either file is corrupt or some part is invalid or missing.

I have already tried the base64 encoded string but still not able to get what is desired. Please suggest a solution to it.

I writing the handler in typescript Node using the SLS framework.